# how to make scanf not ignore spaces and \n in C

Tags: c, char, scanf

so, i am currently studying C code in class, we got an assignemnt for ceaser encoder. I managed to do it, however i now hit an issue regarding the fact they want it to acknowledge spaces and new lines in it. i already checked online and saw more than a few options but there are a few issues:

1) I have to use scanf so do not give a second option

2) I am working with regular chars and not with strings, because in this course they yet to have taught it, so do not offer using char[] or strings or char* because i am not supposed to use them.
thanks in advance.

Comment: "I have to use scanf ... I am working with regular chars and not with strings" --> 
The above are curious requirements as the format to `scanf()` requires a _string_.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can read a single character at a time with `scanf`, and the whitespace will not be ignored:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("Will print all characters typed, use ctrl-D to quit\n");
  char c;
  while (scanf("%c", &c) != EOF) {
    printf("%c", c);
  }
}
```